# Question about ssh remote script execution

Tags: ssh

There are two scripts on HostB

```
# loop.sh
while true; do
  date
  sleep 2
done
```

and

```
# loop12.sh
optv=$1
while true; do
  case $optv in
  2)
    echo "from stderr" >&2
    date >&2
    ;;
  *)
    echo "from stdout"
    date
    ;;
  esac
  sleep 2
done
```

I run `ssh HostB './loop.sh &'` on HostA, the Terminal prints the date every 2 seconds.
When I press `Ctrl + c` to stop`ssh HostB` running on HostA, and check the process with `ps -ef | grep loop` on HostB, the process `loop.sh`  is still there.

I run `ssh HostB './loop12.sh &'` on HostA, the Terminal prints the date every 2 seconds, too.
But when I press `Ctrl + c` to stop`ssh HostB` running on HostA, and check the process with `ps -ef | grep loop12` on HostB, the process `loop12.sh`  is gone.

I just wonder Why the scripts are similar but they have different phenomenon?

Comment: Did you mean loop12.sh at the end?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you for reminding me!